# Chabad nusach for Birkat Hamazon

Tags: chabad, nuschaot, bentching

I noticed that in the last part of Birkat Hamazon, at the level of the pesukim יראו את ה' קדושיו ...

> יְראוּ אֶת יְיָ קְדֹשָׁיו, כִּי אֵין מַחְסוֹר לִירֵאָיו. כְּפִירִים רָשׁוּ וְרָעֵבוּ, וְדֹרְשֵׁי יְיָ לֹא יַחְסְרוּ כָל טוֹב. הוֹדוּ לַיְיָ כִּי טוֹב, כִּי לְעוֹלָם חַסְדּוֹ. פּוֹתֵחַ אֶת יָדֶךָ, וּמַשְׂבִּיעַ לְכָל חַי רָצוֹן. בָּרוּךְ הַגֶּבֶר אֲשֶׁר יִבְטַח בַּיְיָ, וְהָיָה יְיָ מִבְטַחוֹ. נַעַר הָיִיתִי גַּם זָקַנְתִּי, וְלֹא רָאִיתִי צַדִּיק נֶעֱזָב, וְזַרְעוֹ מְבַקֶּשׁ לָחֶם. יְיָ עֹז לְעַמּוֹ יִתֵּן, יְיָ יְבָרֵךְ אֶת עַמּוֹ בַשָּׁלוֹם.

The two last verses aren't present in the bentsh of the siddur Tehilas Hashem (and in Tefila Yeshara). Is there a special reason for skipping them? I can understand that the passuk base haiiti is not easy to be said with cavana

Comment: I am still a naar. So its hard for me to include.

Comment: IIRC it is also typeset with smaller letters in the Sefas Emes siddur, hinting that not everyone said that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See page 30 of this pdf: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/pardes/pardes19-s2.pdf

Basically, he brings many different versions, and posits that at the time of the Alter Rebbe there was not yet a set minhag for the verses recited at the end of birchat hamazon , and the alter rebbe followed the nusach of 2 of the talmidim of the Arizal.